# Transition between decimal or double numbers

Tags: java, android, numbers, transition

Imagine a number *10*, then after user clicks a button it changes to *100*. But how to make an efficient transition

> 10 -> 100,

that will display values like

> 12, 15, 18, ..., 97, 100 over 1 second.

I've seen something like that in "Cookie clicker" but couldn't find anything about that kind of transition in the source code.

I had an idea of a loop *(for number1 < number2, do number1++)*, it will work fine for small numbers, but if 10 changes to 1 billion, then the loop will probably freeze the whole app.

Second idea is to get added value (*100-10=90*) and divide by 30 or 60 frames, and add this value with each frame. But what will happen if frame is dropped? - Probably value will not be added. What if user makes double click or the system adds values automatically?

Hope it gives an idea of what kind of number transition I need.
 Maybe I overlooked and there is a simple approach? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One possible solution would be to use a `ValueAnimator`. Maybe this is what you are looking for. I will show you the example code soon ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this little demo using a `ValueAnimator` will inspire you to find an appropriate solution.
You can specify the duration of the animation (see code) and even adjust the frame-rate by saying `mAnimator.setFrameDelay(frameDelay);`.
By using `animator.isRunning()` or `animator.isStarted()` you can prevent double-click malfunction or other unwanted behaviour while the current animation is runnning.

The Main Activity:

```
/** ValueAnimator demo */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ValueAnimator mAnimator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        mAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(1, 100).setDuration(1000);
        mAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        mAnimator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(final ValueAnimator animator) {

                final Integer value = (Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue();
                tv.setText(String.format("%04d", value));
            }

        });
        mAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {

                super.onAnimationEnd(animator);
                final int endValue = Integer.parseInt((String) tv.getText());
                mAnimator.setIntValues(endValue, endValue + 100);
            }
        });
    }

    /** Button callback */
    public void onClick(final View view) {

        if (!mAnimator.isStarted() && !mAnimator.isRunning()) {
            mAnimator.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Simple demo layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:text="0001" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gimme +100" 
    android:onClick="onClick">
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks, works great for single clicks. I will experiment with it, but maybe you can answer me one more question: can it be adjusted so, that it will be able to properly react on multiple button presses? Like stop animation, get remaining number, add 100 to it, and set new starting and ending values in animation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean?  Do I understand right, if animation is running another click would stop it, if user clicks again, continue animation with new corresponing start and end values?

Comment: If animation is running, another click should immediately restart animation with new corresponding start and end values. If user makes 2 clicks, then it will look like single animation, but final value will be 200 (2 clicks with 100 each)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another demo (hope this answers your 2. question), which implements different behaviour dependent on single click or double-click on the button. Just experiment with it, you now have the basic building blocks to construct own behavour ...

```
/** ValueAnimator demo */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ValueAnimator mAnimator;
    TextView mTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        mAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(1, 100).setDuration(1000);
        mAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        mAnimator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(final ValueAnimator animator) {
                final Integer value = (Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue();
                mTv.setText(String.format("%04d", value));
            }

        });

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                        performAnimation(100);
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                        performAnimation(0);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }

    /** starts animation */
    private void performAnimation(final int offset) {

        if (!mAnimator.isStarted() && !mAnimator.isRunning()) {
            final int endValue = Integer.parseInt((String) mTv.getText());
            mAnimator.setIntValues(endValue + offset, endValue + 100 + offset);
            mAnimator.start();
        }

    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace your layout file, since the click-attribute of the button has been removed:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:text="0001" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gimme +100" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it by using different threads. Only main thread works with UI so you can divide the interval into small intervals and make a transitions in different threads.After send them to main thread and print.  Hope it will help.